# How do I extract the text data between these two fields in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to extract the word Apixaban Tab and it will always be between the +R and -R

+R}}Apixaban tab{{-R

Comment: Can you please tag the database that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You will get what you want running this query:

```
declare @string nvarchar(40) = '+R}}Apixaban tab{{-R', @2ndstring nvarchar(40)

set @2ndstring = right(@string, len(@string) - charindex('}', @string) - 1)

select substring(@2ndstring, 0, charindex('{', @2ndstring))
```

for sure that is now the best solution, but my logic is like that.

Check result/output on [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a747eaa5565768784acf5bd034e8d87)